# JGoodies memory leak?? - Out of Memory Exception when Spring tries to display the view

Tags: java, validation, spring, jgoodies

I am getting an Out of Memory exception sometimes during or after the validation of component happens.  I was trying to profile a large validation result <= 20000, and it worked, so I went bigger.  The exception occurs at values > 20000, does anyone know of any inherent jgoodies memory leaks, with the validation framework, the component binder, or anything else?

> Exception in thread "signal-validationPerformanceTest" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>       at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
>       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
>       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
>       at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:224)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.DefaultValueStyler.style(DefaultValueStyler.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.DefaultValueStyler.style(DefaultValueStyler.java:72)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.DefaultValueStyler.style(DefaultValueStyler.java:100)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.DefaultValueStyler.style(DefaultValueStyler.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.DefaultValueStyler.style(DefaultValueStyler.java:66)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.StylerUtils.style(StylerUtils.java:47)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap.toString(LocalAttributeMap.java:312)
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.DefaultValueStyler.style(DefaultValueStyler.java:78)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.DefaultToStringStyler.styleValue(DefaultToStringStyler.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.DefaultToStringStyler.styleField(DefaultToStringStyler.java:79)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.ToStringCreator.append(ToStringCreator.java:156)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowSessionImpl.toString(FlowSessionImpl.java:207)
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.DefaultValueStyler.style(DefaultValueStyler.java:78)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.DefaultValueStyler.style(DefaultValueStyler.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.DefaultValueStyler.style(DefaultValueStyler.java:72)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.DefaultToStringStyler.styleValue(DefaultToStringStyler.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.DefaultToStringStyler.styleField(DefaultToStringStyler.java:79)
>       at org.springframework.core.style.ToStringCreator.append(ToStringCreator.java:156)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.toString(FlowExecutionImpl.java:499)
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
>       at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:219)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.support.SimpleFlowExecutionRepository.putFlowExecution(SimpleFlowExecutionRepository.java:130)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resume(FlowExecutorImpl.java:226)
>       at com.mason.core.application.flow.ApplicationFlowEngine$SignalEventTask.execute(ApplicationFlowEngine.java:188)
>       at com.mason.core.application.flow.ApplicationFlowEngine$1.run(ApplicationFlowEngine.java:99)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turn on -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError (assuming you have a SUN JVM) and load the heap dump into the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). It should be easy to find out what is needing too much memory.